# Making a property method callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods, python-decorators

I have a class with a property method:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    @property
    def some_method(self):

        return True
```

I want to make a call to **some_method** and store it in as an expression.

For example:

```
some_expr = SomeClass().some_method
```

Should not store the value **True** in **some_expr**; rather should store the expression **SomeClass().some_method** so that it is callable.

How can I implement this?

Comment: why? it will always evaluate to `True` unless you really screw with the class.

Comment: also, i feel like the easiest way is to not use a property. i mean, the whole point of a property is that you don't have to call it but it can be dynamically generated and look like a member var. i guess, again, why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Note, you essentially want to use the `.__get__` callable on the property instance. However, this will require an instance as the first argument, so you could just partially apply some instance:

```
In [6]: class SomeClass(object):
   ...:
   ...:     @property
   ...:     def some_method(self):
   ...:
   ...:         return True
   ...:

In [7]: from functools import partial
```

Then something like:

```
In [9]: some_exp = partial(SomeClass.some_method.__get__, SomeClass())

In [10]: some_exp()
Out[10]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to make a property callable:

#### Code:

```
class CallableProperty(object):

    def __init__(self, instance, name):
        self.instance = instance
        self.name = name

    def __call__(self):
        return getattr(self.instance, self.name)
```

#### Test Code:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    @property
    def some_method(self):
        return True

x = SomeClass()
y = CallableProperty(x, 'some_method')

print(y())
```

#### Result:

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to do this is to do something like:

```
call_prop = lambda: SomeClass().some_prop
```

but there's no good reason you would ever need this.

Answer (score 0):

So- a "property" is a descriptor. What this means is it is an object (everything is an object in python) that has the **get** method defined. When you access a class property, if the object there has the **get** method, python will helpfully call it for you. That decorator takes the provided function and turns it into a **get**(self) method on an object that gets assigned to the class. Great!

If, for some reason, you actually wanted the function instead of for the function to get called, you can access it through the class dictionary...

`f = SomeClass.__dict__['some_method'].__get__`
Which, would allow you to do `f(1)` if the "self" method didn't matter.

If you really wanted to get fancy, you could do `new_f = functools.partial(f, SomeClass())`
Then... `new_f() == True`

Really curious why you would want to do this though ;)